# Function to check the value and add values according to the result

Tags: r, function, dataframe

there!
I have a table:

```
532 obs. of  44 variables
```

Its looks like this:

```
A tibble: 10 x 44
       ID   PVD Vasculitis   CVA   CHF    MI   HTN  COPD
           <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
     1 11    NA         NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA
     2 22     1         NA     1    NA     1     1     1
     3 33    NA         NA    NA    NA     1     1     1
     4 44    NA         NA     1    NA    NA    NA     1
     5 55     1         NA    NA     1     1     1     1
     6 66    NA         NA    NA     1     1     1     1
     7 77    NA         NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
     8 88    1         NA     1     1     1     1     1
     9 99    NA         NA    NA    NA    NA     1     1
    10 1010    NA         NA    NA     1     1     1    NA
    # ... with 36 more variables: TB <dbl>, Diabetes <dbl>,
    #   Liver <dbl>, CRF <dbl>, Dementia <dbl>, Obesity <dbl>,
    #   Hearing_loss <dbl>, Paraplegia <dbl>, `Peptic
    #   _ulcer` <dbl>, Autoimmune <dbl>, Breast_Cancer <dbl>,
    #   Colon_Cancer <dbl>, Anus_Cancer <dbl>,
    #   Stomach_Cancer <dbl>, Pancreas_Cancer <dbl>,
    #   Ovarian_Cancer <dbl>, Cervix_uteri_Cancer <dbl>,
    #   Uterus_Cancer <dbl>, Prostate_Cancer <dbl>,
    #   Melanoma <dbl>, Lymphoma <dbl>, Leukemia <dbl>,
    #   Thyroid_Cancer <dbl>, Head_and_neck_Cancer <dbl>,
    #   Kidney_Cancer <dbl>, Adrenal_Cancer <dbl>,
    #   Bone_Cancer <dbl>, Testicular_Cancer <dbl>,
    #   Skin_Cancer <dbl>, Urinary_Cancer <dbl>,
    #   Liver_Cancer <dbl>, Musculoskeletal_Cancer <dbl>,
    #   Multiple_myeloma <dbl>, CNS_Cancer <dbl>,
    #   Unknown_primary_Cancer <dbl>, solid <dbl>
```

So in the first column are unique IDs, the subsequent columns are the names of different diseases (no repetitions). The values in rows 1 are if there's a disease and if NA there isn't, respectively.
For example, patient number 55 (5th row) have "PVD", "CHF", "MI", "HTN", "COPD" and so on.
I also created a vector with the names of cancers (these are the names of columns 19 to 43).
I want to write a function that will check this table, and if the column names match the cancers names of my vector, it will check if this row (number of patient) has a cancer in the matching column (if there is a flag 1), it adds a flag to the last column with the name "solid". At least one coincidence is enough. And so for all the patients.
For example, the same patient 55 if he has, say, a "Colon_cancer" (column 20), he should add 1 to the "solid" column, if he has some other cancer it does not matter.
I try something like this, but without success, and I'm stuck:

```
solid_tumor <- function(x){
    x <- as.data.frame(x)
    for (i in length(x)) {
        if (colnames(x) %in% tumors) {
            if(any(x==1)) {
               x[i] <- 1 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thank you.

Comment: I would recommend treating your function as if it is always in it's own environment.  Add `tumors` as an argument for the function to pull.

Answer (score 1):

## A pivoting approach, using `tidyverse`

It seems to me that it might be best if you pivot your data so it is easier to write functions on.

#### Sample Dataframe:

First lets make a sample dataframe that makes it easier for others to consider this problem and the solution in the future:

```
library(tidyverse)
na_or_1 <- c("NA", 1)
df <- tibble(
  ID     = sample(10:100, 30),
  car    = sample(na_or_1, 30, replace = T, prob = c(.05, .95)),
  bug    = sample(na_or_1, 30, replace = T, prob = c(.05, .95)),
  blast  = sample(na_or_1, 30, replace = T, prob = c(.05, .95)),
  opt    = sample(na_or_1, 30, replace = T, prob = c(.05, .95)),
  star   = sample(na_or_1, 30, replace = T, prob = c(.05, .95)),
  queue  = sample(na_or_1, 30, replace = T, prob = c(.05, .95)),
  man    = sample(na_or_1, 30, replace = T, prob = c(.05, .95)),
  ring   = sample(na_or_1, 30, replace = T, prob = c(.05, .95)),
  happy  = sample(na_or_1, 30, replace = T, prob = c(.05, .95)),
  after  = sample(na_or_1, 30, replace = T, prob = c(.05, .95)),
  hug    = sample(na_or_1, 30, replace = T, prob = c(.05, .95)),
  dragon = sample(na_or_1, 30, replace = T, prob = c(.05, .95))
)
```

#### Pivot Longer

Now we can use the `pivot_longer` function to pivot all the data longer against the ID column.

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value))
```

This makes an output that is:
`ID` `Name` `value` where name == the name of the column (cancer names) and value == 1 (the NAs are all filtered out)

This makes it much easier for a function to apply logic to what you're asking it to do.

#### Mutate using `case_when`

Using a vector of `tumors` I can apply a `case_when` logic and `mutate` a new column `solid`.  I took out the NA filter because it occurred to me that you will want your DF to be mostly unchanged.

```
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>% 
    # filter( !is.na(value) ) %>% 
    mutate(solid = case_when(name %in% tumors &
                           !is.na(value) ~ 1,
                             T ~ NA_real_))
```

#### Pivot Wider

Finally, I will undo the longer pivot using `pivot_wider`.  I will take the names from the name column that was originally created using the pivot longer.

```
 df %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>% 
# filter( !is.na(value) ) %>% 
mutate(solid = case_when(name %in% tumors &
                           !is.na(value) ~ 1,
                         T ~ NA_real_)) %>% 
pivot_wider(
  names_from = name
)
```

#### Function Solution

```
myfunction <- function(df, tumors){
 df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>% 
  # filter( !is.na(value) ) %>% 
  mutate(solid = case_when(name %in% tumors &
                           !is.na(value) ~ 1,
                         T ~ NA_real_)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name
  )
}
```

#### Example

Now when I take a vector of tumors I can put this into the function and the df and come with the answer to your original question.

```
tumors <- c("hug", "happy", "man")
myfunction(df, tumors)


# # A tibble: 32 x 14
#      ID solid car   bug   blast opt   star  queue man   ring  happy after hug   dragon
#     <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
# 1    16    NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
# 2    98    NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
# 3    74    NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
# 4    50    NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
# 5    50     1 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
# 6    29    NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
# 7    94    NA NA    NA    NA    1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
# 8    19    NA NA    1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
# 9    46    NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
# 10   15    NA NA    1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other ways to look at this.

### Simple function

This demonstrates the simplicity and flexibility of a simple functional approach:

```r
func <- function(x, candidates) {
  cnames <- intersect(candidates, colnames(x))
  if (length(cnames)) {
    +(rowSums(!is.na(subset(x, select = cnames))) > 0)
  } else rep(0L, nrow(x))
}

dat$solid <- func(dat, c("CHF", "MI"))
dat
#      ID PVD Vasculitis CVA CHF MI HTN COPD solid
# 1    11  NA         NA  NA  NA NA   1   NA     0
# 2    22   1         NA   1  NA  1   1    1     1
# 3    33  NA         NA  NA  NA  1   1    1     1
# 4    44  NA         NA   1  NA NA  NA    1     0
# 5    55   1         NA  NA   1  1   1    1     1
# 6    66  NA         NA  NA   1  1   1    1     1
# 7    77  NA         NA  NA  NA NA  NA   NA     0
# 8    88   1         NA   1   1  1   1    1     1
# 9    99  NA         NA  NA  NA NA   1    1     0
# 10 1010  NA         NA  NA   1  1   1   NA     1
```

### Tidy-friendly

Unfortunately, `dplyr` doesn't make it particularly easy to pass *all columns* to a function within `mutate`. (I'm sure somebody will recommend `c_across()` ... I have yet to find its use elegant in something like this.)

A first stab might use the dot `.`:

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(solid = func(., c("CHF", "MI")))
```

which works fine in the absence of any grouping, but it always uses the whole frame regardless of groups, so if that is ever a consideration, then you'll get an error:

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  # I know this is equivalent to rowwise() with this data
  mutate(solid = func(., c("CHF", "MI")))
# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `solid`.
# x Input `solid` can't be recycled to size 1.
# i Input `solid` is `func(., c("CHF", "MI"))`.
# i Input `solid` must be size 1, not 10.
# i The error occured in group 1: ID = 11.
```

So the simple workaround is to just `do` it.

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  do(mutate(., solid = func(., c("CHF", "MI"))))
```

(I realize that grouping is not relevant for *this* data, but applying a "simple" non-tidyverse function to all columns of the current frame can be useful elsewhere, and honoring groups is important.)